# What does the word "literal" or "actual" mean as in a literal or actual something?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

I mean like when someone uses a certain word with more than one meaning, they often say it's a "literal" something. For example: (something I made up)

"John's corporate seal logo for his company has a literal seal on it"

---

"The [sign-in seal](https://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/what-is-yahoo-sign-in-seal) for his Yahoo account is a picture of an actual seal"

---

What is a "literal" seal exactly? What is the usage of the word "literal"? Literal and actual are supposed to mean exactly, so what does it mean in this context?

Comment: Means it might look like this:  https://images.app.goo.gl/EszwZphA4S88o1ER9

Comment: If you use a word literally, you use it in its correct, dictionary meaning and not as a metaphor. For example, if I said that someone was _literally forced_ to sign a document, it would imply that it wasn't just by psychological pressure but by someone standing over them and forcing a pen into their hand. However, _seal_ has more than one literal meaning, so it isn't really appropriate to use _literal_ here.

Comment: *Literal* is a tricky one. It’s hard to be generic with an answer when the word has acquired its own antonym as a secondary meaning.

Comment: In common jargon, "actual" is more literal than "literal".

Comment: The first problem here is that there are two words 'seal'. Homonyms. Next, if (as in the first instance seems likely) 'seal' is the sea mammal here, a literal one needs to get back to the sea fairly quickly. 'Literal' may acceptably be used to single out the 'primary / original English' sense of a word, but not to single out one homonym rather than another.

Answer (score 1):

"John's corporate seal logo for his company has a literal seal on it” is not idiomatic; “an actual seal on it” as far preferable.

“**Literal**” = “within the true meaning (or dictionary definition) of the word” – however “seal” has several “true meanings” – it can refer to several sorts of seal – they can be of a metal/plastic/paper/printed ink, etc. or, of **sealing wax** . Thus “literal as so vague as to be meaningless.
However, “**actual**” usually refers the reader to the most traditional form of a seal **in the context**, and **in the context** that you have given, “seal” would be one of sealing wax and embossed with some legend.

That said, the example is flawed as **seal** could also be the pinniped animal - a seal - or a seal of sealing wax. You will have to rewrite the sentence.

OED

> **Literal**
>
> c. Of, relating to, or designating the primary, original, or
> etymological sense of a word, or the exact sense expressed by the
> actual wording of a phrase or passage, as distinguished from any
> extended sense, metaphorical meaning, or underlying significance.

> **Actual**
>
> b. As an intensifier.
>
> (a) In weakened use, emphasizing the exact or particular identity of
> a following noun: precise, exact.